# Can't boot into Ubuntu after installing GNOME 16.04 (stuck at blank purple screen)

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, nvidia, gnome

I've also tried booting through recovery mode but that just gets stuck at a black screen instead. Everything was running fine until I tried booting into Ubuntu this morning, even last night it was working fine after installing GNOME. I have a Nvidia 1070 but all the graphics drivers should be up to date. Any ideas on what to do? Windows is still booting up fine.

Comment: What are the updated Display drivers you have installed?  Are you able to get in when adding **nomodeset** to your grub commandline (hitting **`e`** to edit at the black screen).  Add this to the line with `quiet spash`.  If you are able to boot with the parameter, use `Additional Drivers` from the `System Settings/Software & Updates` app.

Comment: I'll check when I'm home and edit this but I'm fairly certain it's the 375 drivers.

Comment: Okay, I tried the nomodeset thing and I still can't boot in. What is there left to try?

Comment: Was it the very same effect, the purple screen only?  Try removing the workds quiet and splash and have only nomodeset there.

Comment: It was the same effect but I tried it again and it actually let me go to command line when I did nomodeset. Then I followed the advice of Dy1anW on [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058251) thread about reconfiguring lightdm and it ended up booting fine!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!  I'll add the tested information to an answer for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using nomodeset to get far enough to open command line with CTRL + ALT + F1. After that I entered

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm start
```

from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058251

Answer (score 0):

**How to resolve the purple screen and be able to login:**

At the black grub menu when booting hit **`E`** to edit your grub commandline.  Add `nomodeset` to the line that has `quiet splash` as a parameter.  Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue to boot.

Once logged in, while there may be a number of fixes, but most common one is to check the installed graphics drivers and update them.  To ones better fitted for your environment.

You can edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and add the `nomodeset` grub command there to ensure you can login while you test compatible settings.

To check check if the `nomodeset` is still needed, you can use the Grub Boot menu and remove it from the commandline.  If your updated setting works, you can remove the line from your `/etc/default/grub`.

If you make a change to the `/etc/default/grub`, be sure to update the grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```